# GLFW Context Error

Tags: opengl, glfw

(to start this is more theoretical, and I cannot provide a working example, you'll see why. so please bear with me)

I am creating a Plugin for Rhino3D that requires me to create a GLFW context, init Glew and render something.

Then I need to go back and render something, but was trying to keep the GLFW window around so I could call it.

The issue I have is Glew on the 2nd run returns 1 (no GL context) and the buffers return a 1282 error .. for invalid operations since there is no GLEW init.

I tried a glfwMakeContextCurrent , and checked the pointers were both valid and the same.

But I still have the issues

Is it because Rhino has another thread running, or is there another way to grab the context back from GLFW to ensure I have everything setup.

Comment: Are you using GLEW MX? For multi-context applications you are supposed to use that. It doesn't much matter on platforms that use GLX, but WGL is very finicky about loading extensions in an application that uses multiple contexts because they can have completely different feature sets.

Comment: complicated.. I get a "main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol glewContextInit" error when I try to use it